# Constant Variables in Javascript

Tags: javascript

I am trying to have some const global variables which I can use in the javascript and I came out with this code and picking up from some answers referred in SO. But it seems that I have a little mistake somewhere which I couldn't spot. Can someone help me with this?

in testQuery.js

```
(function (window, undefined) {

    var testQuery = function(obj) {
        if (!(this instanceof testQuery)) {
            return new testQuery(obj);
        }
    }

    var MYGLOBALS = function() {
        var globals = {
            foo : "bar",
            batz : "blah"           
        }

        return {
            getValue : function(s) {
                return globals[s];
            }
        }
    }();

    window.testQuery = testQuery;

}) (window);
```

---

and in the html javascript tag i have this line of code.

in testQuery.html file

```
<html>
  <head>
    <script src="testQuery.js"></script>
    <script>

       function onClick() {

             alert(MYGLOBALS.getValue("foo"));
       }

    </script>
  </head>

  <body>

      <input type="button" onclick="onClick()">

  </body>

</html>
```

Comment: What makes you think you have a mistake?  What error output/behaviour are you getting, and what did you expect?

Comment: @Andrzej Doyle i am suppose to expect a pop up box that returns 'bar' from what i understand from the code. however, it seems that it is not responding to what i understand.

Comment: Part of the problem understanding it might have been that it was misleadingly (and inconsistently) indented. I've updated the indentation to be more standard, which may help (and will certainly help people reading the question). **Edit**: And now I've done it again (your edit wiped it out).

Comment: @T.J Crowder sorry about that, i was trying to add in the codes in the html file before i saw this comment.

Answer (score 3):

The variable `MYGLOBALS` is local to your scoping function (the big outermost function that has no name), so it can only be accessed from within that function.

I'm not sure what you mean by "...in the html javascript tag..." but if the `alert` you've quoted is outside that scoping function, `MYGLOBALS` is out of scope for it.

---

**Update**: The thing about JavaScript scope is that it's *much simpler* than people think it is. Variables declared with `var` are private to the scope (function or global; JavaScript has no block-level scope so just `{}` doesn't do it) in which they're declared, and sub-scopes of that scope (e.g., functions declared or define within it). And scope is entirely *lexical* — that is, it is what you see in the source code, not dictated by some other runtime structure. They don't pop out of that scope unless you see code somewhere explicitly making that happen, as with your `window.testQuery = testQuery;` line, which explicitly makes `testQuery` a property on `window` and therefore a global variable. (And even then, it's not that the variable has popped out of the scope, just that you've created a *new* property referring to the same thing which is more broadly-accessible.)

---

**Update 2**: Re your comment

> Actually what I am trying to do is to create something like what you would see when you are doing programming in other language where there will be a final static integer which you can put into the parameters fields on the functions you call. is there a better way of doing it? For example, in visual basic its something like me.background = Color.YELLOW. what I want is to have a static variable which will represent that YELLOW color.

JavaScript doesn't have user-defined constants, and doesn't have enums. *(Update: Both of those things may change with ES6.)* What you do instead is define an object with the properties, e.g.:

```
var COLORS = {
    RED: "#FF0000",
    BLUE: "#0000FF",
    // ...
    GREEN: "#00FF00"
};
```

Those *aren't* constants, there's nothing to keep anyone from assigning to `COLORS.RED` except your telling them not to.

*(Update: In ES5, we can make those properties constant using `Object.defineProperties`, like this:*

```
var COLORS = Object.defineProperties({}, {
    RED:   {value: "#FF0000"},
    BLUE:  {value: "#0000FF"},
    // ...
    GREEN: {value: "#00FF00"}
});
```

*When you define a property that way, by default it's not writable.)*

For what you're doing, you probably want the module pattern, where you have a single global symbol whose value is an object, and everything else is properties on that object:

```
(function() {
    var mod;

    // Create the global, and also give ourselves a convenient alias for it (`mod`)
    window.MyModule = mod = {};

    // Colors
    mod.COLORS = {
        RED: "#FF0000",
        BLUE: "#0000FF",
        // ...
        GREEN: "#00FF00"
    };

    mod.testQuery = MyModule_testQuery;
    function MyModule_testQuery() {
        // Do something
    }

})();

alert(MyModule.COLORS.RED); // #FF0000
MyModule.testQuery();       // Do something
```

Or if you prefer, that `testQuery` function could be defined like this:

```
    mod.testQuery = function() {
        // Do something
    };
```

...but then the function is anonymous, and I'm [not a fan of anonymous functions](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2010/03/anonymouses-anonymous.html). (Note that there's *nothing* special about the name `MyModule_testQuery`, that's purely my naming convention.)

---

**Somewhat off topic**:

Regarding this line where we're publishing our global symbol above:

```
// Create the global, and also give ourselves a convenient alias for it (`mod`)
window.MyModule = mod = {};
```

Note that that is very specific to browser environments. We could make it applicable to any JavaScript environment with a trivial change:

```
// Create the global, and also give ourselves a convenient alias for it (`mod`)
this.MyModule = mod = {};
```

That works because we're the ones who call the outermost scoping function, and so we know that we're not calling it with any particular `this` value (`this` in JavaScript — unlike some other languages — is determined *entirely* by how a function is called, not where or how it's defined). So since we know we're not using any special `this` value, we know that it will be the global object, because that's how JavaScript works. And the global object is `window` on web browsers (effectively; technically `window` is a property on the global object that refers back to itself).

Comment: @T.J. Crowder but doesn't this line window.testQuery = testQuery; makes this whole function accessible outside the scope?

Comment: @simplified: It makes the symbol `window.testQuery` accessible outside the function (makes `testQuery` a property on `window`, e.g. a global variable). It has no effect on `MYGLOBALS` at all.

Comment: @T.J Crowder does this means that i have to refer to testQuery to access myglobals? like testQuery.MYGLOBALS or something?

Comment: @simplified: You could do that, if you put `MYGLOBALS` on `testQuery` as a property. Then you could access them as `window.testQuery.MYGLOBALS` (or just `testQuery.MYGLOBALS`).

Comment: @T.J Crowder actually what I am trying to do is to create something like what you would see when you are doing programming in other language where there will be a final static integer which you can put into the parameters fields on the functions you call. is there a better way of doing it? For example, in visual basic its something like me.background = Color.YELLOW. what I want is to have a static variable which will represent that YELLOW color.

Comment: @simplified: I've added an example

Comment: @T.J Crowder thanks. the example was really helpful. i seem to have understand what i am trying to do much better.

Comment: @simplified: No worries. Not trying to sell my blog, but you may find these articles of use: *[Mythical methods](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2008/03/mythical-methods.html)*, *[You must remember `this`](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2008/04/you-must-remember-this.html)*, *[Closures are not complicated](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2008/02/closures-are-not-complicated.html)*, and (more advanced) *[Simple, efficient supercalls in JavaScript](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2009/09/simple-efficient-supercalls-in.html)* That last may well help with defining modules of things, once you get there.

Answer (score 1):

http://jsfiddle.net/vXu7m/1/

Some syntactic cleanup, and attaching you MYGLOBALS to the window object should do what you want.